# Tracking down a dependency initiated by "other" in dev tools

Tags: javascript, css, dependencies, google-chrome-devtools, google-font-api

I'm trying to find the initiator of a Google font. There is nothing returned for a search within project files for the reference. Within dev tools it shows `http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700` but its initiator is `other`.

Any experience on tracking down dependencies, specifically ones without an explicit initiating file, would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Google Maps API pulls in the Roboto font. I've opened a ticket at Google API forums regarding how many dependencies we have no control over when using their library.

So the answer is:
Look to your libraries which may pull in their own dependencies. Within dev tools their 'source' might be listed as "other".